# Are nested manifests possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

If manifest A contains the directive `//= require_directory .` and one of the files in that directory is manifest B, are the files indicated in the second manifest automatically included in the precompilation? If so, is there a directive one can place in A in order to skip B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyGuides says about [the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html): "You can have as many manifest files as you need".

To nest them just add `//= require` directives wherever needed.

In order to "comment out" a directive just remove the equal sign (for both css and js).

For example:

*app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

```
//= require dependencies
//= require_tree .
```

*app/assets/javascripts/dependencies.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
// require turbolinks
//= require ace
//= require theme-monokai
//= require mode-javascript
//= require mode-ruby
//= require websocket_rails/main
//= require socket_helpers
alert("this is being called from a manifest file which was required from another manifest file")
```

Comment: I don't think that guide addresses my question. In their examples none of the manifest directives point to a manifest. Do you have another citation?

Comment: @planarian To cite the same link, `You can have as many manifest files as you need. For example, the admin.css and admin.js manifest could contain the JS and CSS files that are used for the admin section of an application.`. Manifest are just regular JS files with the preprocessor directive `//=`. I just tested it and works, see my edited answer for an example

Comment: Ended up going about this a different way, but I'll take your word for it.